# How to get the data from a node read stream to use it for a HTTP post request?

Tags: node.js, http-post, node.js-stream

I'd like to send an HTTP post request using the `scoped-http-client`, like this:

```
client('http://url-to-post-to.com/').post({filedata: <data from stream>})
```

How would I pass in the data of a node stream?

Answer (score 0):

[From their documentation](https://github.com/technoweenie/node-scoped-http-client), you can get access to the [http.ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) which is a [writable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable).  From there, you can just pipe the file data to the request.  For example, if you were to send JSON file data:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    scopedClient = require("scoped-http-client");

var file = fs.createReadStream("./test.json");

var client = scopedClient.create("http://url-to-post-to.com/").header("Content-Type", "application/json");

client.post(function(err, req) {
    file.pipe(req);
});
```